# Any Language that can be generated LL1 Grammar is regular. True/False

Tags: context-free-grammar, regular-language, compiler-construction

I am reading about grammars, I have a question is every language generated by LL(1) grammar is regular? I know that every regular language can be generated by LL(1) grammar.

Comment: False. (with 50% probability)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For example, take the following grammar:

```
E  ->  TE' | T
E' -> +TE' | -TE' | T
T  ->  FT' | F
T' -> *FT' | /FT' | F
F  ->  cte | (E)
```

It is the well known grammar for arithmetic expressions, written in LL(1) form. It is also a well known non-regular language, since it contains a Dick language (balanced parenthesis). This is of course not a formal proof that such language is not regular, but the proof is not very difficult, using the pumping lemma, and it should be easy to find on the web.